What Specific Optimizations Can ARM Implementations Do That x86 Ones Cannot (And Vice-Versa And Risc-V)
I believe this question is slightly different from others (ex: Why exactly does the x86 (primarily x86-64) instruction set consume more power than reduced instruction sets like arm?)
This question is more about a pseudo-itemized list of constraints that ARM, RISC-V, x86, and others have that are not present on their peers, and what specific results it has on performance / die area / etc. Interesting stories even if the architecture is obsolete would be great too, of course.
Example 1: x86 is fairly strict in terms of memory ordering (which they tried to fix in Itanium but AMD won with x86-64). How does this affect various IP blocks, workloads, etc.?
Example 2: x86 has legacy cruft (although ARM is getting pretty big too). What parts of the CPU does this correspond to? How much die area / internal latency / etc. does it typically correspond to? Etc.?
(Let's assume hypothetical chips that are the same fabrication process, power target, and die area.)

I worked at Intel (circa P Pro/P II) on chipsets. This question would take at least one book to cover well. Stripping it down to an over-simplification which is only a cartoon caricature and misses much, I might only say that RISC-V intelligently incorporates many decades of ISA and FAB and application space knowledge and leverages that historical experience and knowledge about as well as possible, around a decade ago. Other designs have two feet in the grave, so to speak. But they also have advanced features coming from long maturity, too. RISC-V has much ahead of it to catch up. Fastly, tho.

Yeah, I figured that it was about as loaded of a question as the topic could get. I also assume some of that is internal/proprietary. Hard to describe the question otherwise, though, so I leaned into wording that would promote specific and low-level. Thanks for the insight btw!

OoO (out of order) was first introduced with the P Pro, when I was there working on and studying the implementation at Intel. (Had to check out "secret" books that I was responsible returning -- they carefully guarded and tracked those books.) I had a wonderful discussion over 2 days with Dr. Hennessey at MIPS in 1986 where he discussed, at length, die space trade-offs. The point here is that your question is just way over-broad. I could go on for hours. And I'm no expert. Just a stupid grunt with a limited perspective on a few things. I've designed CPUs. But I'm no Dr. Patterson + team.

And, frankly, I've not kept up to date. I'm studying various designs and verilog codings for RISC-V, with differing numbers of pipeline stages. I've not yet found an OoO design at Github, yet, though. If I see one, it goes immediately onto my study list. But I know they are already being made (China and at Intel, already.) Just haven't laid hands on one yet. Anyway. Best wishes.

When you say "ARM", do you mean the original ARM from backintheday? As in the actual core implementing the first version of that ISA? Or do you just refer to the ISA family in general (which is quite large, and diverse: there's no single "ARM processor standard")? Or are you specifically referring to things that are impossible to implement on the x86_64 + all the modern extensions ISA vs the ARMv8something + all the modern extensions ISA? I'm a bit confused, because at the end of your question you bring in fabrication, but neither "ARM" nor "x86" nor RISC-V are a specific implementation.

To drive that example home a bit, hoping to help you narrow your question down, maybe: Both current Intel Atom and AMD Zen are x86_64 implementations, and modern ones. Drastically different in performance, timing, etc. Both the ARM in an Apple M3 laptop and in a 90€ entry-level smart phone implement ARMv8; as you can imagine, beyond being able to execute the same code, they're not that similar! (with RISC-V things get a bit more perplexing, because what the ISA actually supports, from compressed instruction set to vectorized operations, is in the name suffixes; RV64IMACPH != RV32E)
